# Trouble installing EE 3.5.3, ee/legacy/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_connection.php:122

Tags: ee3, install

Just installed latest EE 3.5.3. Running on php 5.6. I've performed the ee_server_wizard test which passed everything.

Did 2 fresh installs and when I try login at admin.php I'm getting.

> ee/legacy/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_connection.php:122

Any ideas on how to fix? Thanks, Ted

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'my-database.exp_comments' doesn't exist:
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM (`exp_comments` as Comment_comments) LEFT JOIN `exp_channel_titles` AS Entry_channel_titles ON `Entry_channel_titles`.`entry_id` = `Comment_comments`.`entry_id` LEFT JOIN `exp_channel_data` as Entry_channel_data ON `Entry_channel_data`.`entry_id` = `Entry_channel_titles`.`entry_id` WHERE ( `Comment_comments`.`site_id` = '1' AND `Entry_channel_titles`.`status` = 'closed' ) LIMIT 18446744073709551615

ee/legacy/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_connection.php:122
```

and a stack trace that includes 13 items.

Comment: Have you found the answer to this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because I had a similar problem with the `exp_comments` table during an upgrade from 1.x through 3.x to 4/5. For EE 3.5.17, the table looks like this on a fresh install:

```
CREATE TABLE `exp_comments` (
 `comment_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `site_id` int(4) DEFAULT '1',
 `entry_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
 `channel_id` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
 `author_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
 `status` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '0',
 `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `url` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `location` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `ip_address` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `comment_date` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `edit_date` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `comment` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
 KEY `entry_id` (`entry_id`),
 KEY `channel_id` (`channel_id`),
 KEY `author_id` (`author_id`),
 KEY `status` (`status`),
 KEY `site_id` (`site_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: I have the same issue guys - can someone address this>

Comment: There are a couple of things you can do. You can manually modify your table to look like what is described in my answer, or you can delete your comments table and re-create it. My website did not use comments so I just re-created the table and then continued the upgrade process. If this doesn't help, you might need to reach out to someone who understands databases.